# How to compare elements and merge if condition satisfies within arraylist?

Tags: java

i have list of trades, each trades has some attributes like source now, from the list of trades, i want to get all trades that have same source value and combine them together into one trade, for example

```
tradeName      quote           source            quantity      price 
Google          GOOG           Goldman Sachs        15           610  
Microsoft       MSFT           Barclays             400          28
Google          GOOG           Goldman Sachs        45           610  
Google          GOOG           Goldman Sachs        40           610  
Microsoft       MSFT           Barclays             1000          28
```

now based on source information, i should combine trades, so my updated list of trade would be

```
tradeName      quote           source            quantity        price 
Google          GOOG           Goldman Sachs        100           610  
Microsoft       MSFT           Barclays             1400           28
```

I am not sure about comparison part, how to go about solving it?

---

Tried following approach,

```
for (Trade trade : tradeList)
{
   //Not sure how to compare this.trade.source with all sources 
   //of all trades present in the trade.
   //Logic should be if source matches then quantity should be added 
   //but am not sure how comparison would work.  
}

Class Trade
{

private tradeName;
private quote;
private source;
private quantity;
private price;

//Getters and Setters for each of above mentioned attributes. 

}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you need to know how to write the loop? The comparison within the loop? What precisely do you need to know? A pseudocode algorithm?

Comment: @ngmiceli :  I am iterating through the loop but now how would i do comparison within the loop with all the elements of the arraylist, this is where am hung up.

Comment: If you show us what you've written so far for iterating through the loop, we can better help

Comment: @ngmiceli: added updates to question.

Comment: Thanks- one more question. How is a trade represented? I would think each trade is its own `Trade` object that you defined, but `String[] trade` in your loop suggests otherwise

Comment: @ngmiceli: it's trade object, i have created trade class that am using.

Comment: What do you do with price fluctuations?

Comment: @Rachel do you want your result when elements are ideally equals? What I want to say is: all your attributes must have the same value to consider the object is the same?

Comment: @axcdnt : not all should be same, meaning i need to have two attributes same in my code but as for example, need to compare on source.

Comment: @Woot4Moo : Price fluctuation would be weighted out.

Comment: @Rachel if I really got what you need, check the answer I post right before. BTW, when you say combine, do you mean sum some value or something like that?

Comment: @Rachel please check my answer. I've just changed the way loop works. Obviously you can improve that simple logic, but works the way you need now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I would agree that using a Hashmap could be more efficient, I prefer trying to keep to the O.P's provided method. If we're going to iterate over every member, let's check if we've found that member so far. If so, modify him. If not, add him.  I suggest doing all of this to a new list, then doing whatever you want with the new list (setting the old to the new, printing the new, emailing the new to the president of Russia, whatever).

So how about something like follows? (I didn't compile this so excuse any typos)

```
//Create a new list to store our "simplified" results into
ArrayList<Trade> newTradeList = new ArrayList<Trade>(tradeList.size());

//For each trade in the old list, call it "trade" and...
for(Trade trade : tradeList){

    //First we ask, is there already a trade in this list with the same source?
    //indexOf finds where in the array the element lives. I store that result in index
    int index = newTradeList.indexOf(trade);

    //If the element isn't in our list yet, indexOf will return -1.
    //If the result is NOT -1, then we have already seen a trade with this source before
    if(index != -1) {
         //In that case, get that element. We know what index it lives at so grab it.
         Trade t = newTradeList.get(index);
         //Then, do whatever operations to combine the two trades. I assumed you add the quantities. 
         //So the trade in our new list's quantity should be what it was, plus the new trade's quantity
         t.setQuantity(t.getQuantity() + trade.getQuantity());
    } 

    //But if we have never seen this source before, let's add it to our our new list
    else {
         newTradeList.add(trade);
    }
}
```

This is, of course, making a few assumptions. In order for `.indexOf` to work, you'll need your `Trade` class to have the `equals` method defined appropriately (check if source, or source and price are the same- whatever seems right). If you redefine `equals`, you really should also define `hashCode`. It also assumed you have a method `.addQuantity` just because it made the code cleaner than a combination of gets and sets.

---

HashMap's have the advantage of nearly instant (O(1)) checks to see if an element already exists, and ensures that elements in it are unique (as a hashmap is a Set, and a set can not have duplicate elements).   The code would look pretty similar, except we could take advantage of HashMap's `containsKey` method, rather than `indexOf`.

Comment: i can change it to hashMap, i do not have any such constraints.

Comment: If you can let me know what line(s) in particular, maybe I could better help?

Answer (score 3):

I think I'd create a `HashMap<String, Trade>`, using `tradeName+quote+source` as a key, then add each trade from the list to the appropriate item in the map.

Example:

```
Map<String, Trade> map = new HashMap<String, Trade>();
for (Trade trade : tradeList) {
    String key = trade.tradeName + "#" + trade.quote + "#" + trade.source; // signature, what you merge by 
    if (map.containsKey(key)) {
        map.put(key, trade); // the first trade with such a signature 
    } else {
        // not the first, so merge it with the existing one
        map.get(key).add(trade); // you'll have to implement the Trade.add() method
    }
}
List<Trade> merged = new LinkedList<Trade>(map.values());
```

Comment: can you provide more detailed example

Comment: ladies and gentlemen, please comment when downvoting.

Comment: @Rachel check the edit. This assumes, of course, that the pound symbol ("#") does not occur in either of the key fields. If it does, pick one that does not.

Comment: @Qnan shouldn't line 4 be this: 

```if (!map.containsKey(key)) {```

Answer (score 0):

Please, check this 2 approaches:

Java Bean:

```
public class Trade {

private String tradeName;
private String quote;
private String source;
private Integer quantity;
private Integer price;

public String getTradeName() {
    return tradeName;
}

public void setTradeName(String tradeName) {
    this.tradeName = tradeName;
}

public String getQuote() {
    return quote;
}

public void setQuote(String quote) {
    this.quote = quote;
}

public String getSource() {
    return source;
}

public void setSource(String source) {
    this.source = source;
}

public Integer getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public Integer getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(Integer price) {
    this.price = price;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((source == null) ? 0 : source.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Trade other = (Trade) obj;
    if (source == null) {
        if (other.source != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!source.equals(other.source))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("Trade [tradeName=");
    builder.append(tradeName);
    builder.append(", quote=");
    builder.append(quote);
    builder.append(", source=");
    builder.append(source);
    builder.append(", quantity=");
    builder.append(quantity);
    builder.append(", price=");
    builder.append(price);
    builder.append("]");
    return builder.toString();
}
}
```

-- EDIT --

Check this, it's just quite simple:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TradeTest {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Trade t1 = new Trade();
    t1.setPrice(610);
    t1.setQuantity(15);
    t1.setQuote("GOOG");
    t1.setSource("Goldman Sachs");
    t1.setTradeName("Google");

    Trade t2 = new Trade();
    t2.setPrice(28);
    t2.setQuantity(400);
    t2.setQuote("MSFT");
    t2.setSource("Barclays");
    t2.setTradeName("Microsoft");

    Trade t3 = new Trade();
    t3.setPrice(610);
    t3.setQuantity(45);
    t3.setQuote("GOOG");
    t3.setSource("Goldman Sachs");
    t3.setTradeName("Google");

    Trade t4 = new Trade();
    t4.setPrice(610);
    t4.setQuantity(40);
    t4.setQuote("GOOG");
    t4.setSource("Goldman Sachs");
    t4.setTradeName("Google");

    Trade t5 = new Trade();
    t5.setPrice(28);
    t5.setQuantity(1000);
    t5.setQuote("MSFT");
    t5.setSource("Barclays");
    t5.setTradeName("Microsoft");

    List<Trade> trades = new ArrayList<Trade>();
    trades.add(t1);
    trades.add(t2);
    trades.add(t3);
    trades.add(t4);
    trades.add(t5);

    List<Trade> googleTrades = new ArrayList<Trade>();
    List<Trade> microsoftTrades = new ArrayList<Trade>();

    Integer googleQuantities = 0;
    Integer microsoftQuantities = 0;

    for (Trade trade : trades) {
        if (trade.getSource().equals("Goldman Sachs")) {
            googleTrades.clear();
            googleQuantities += trade.getQuantity();
            trade.setQuantity(googleQuantities);
            googleTrades.add(trade);
        } else if (trade.getSource().equals("Barclays")) {
            microsoftTrades.clear();
            microsoftQuantities += trade.getQuantity();
            trade.setQuantity(microsoftQuantities);
            microsoftTrades.add(trade);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Google trades: \n");
    System.out.println(googleTrades);
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("Microsoft trades: \n");
    System.out.println(microsoftTrades);

}
```

}

Check if this works for you.

Answer (score -1):

I feel this should do.

```
Trade gsTrades = new Trade();
    Trade barclaysTrades = new Trade();

    for(Trade trade: tradeList){
        if(trade.getSource().equals("GS")){
            gsTrades.setQuantity(gsTrades.getQuantity()+trade.getQuantity());
            gsTrades.setPrice(gsTrades.getPrice()+trade.getPrice());
        }else{
            barclaysTrades.setQuantity(barclaysTrades.getQuantity()+trade.getQuantity());
            barclaysTrades.setPrice(barclaysTrades.getPrice()+trade.getQuantity());
        }
    }
    System.out.println("GS trade details = " + gsTrades.toString());
    System.out.println("Barclays trade details = " + barclaysTrades.toString());
```

Comment: This would not work as i have only shared an example here and my list has like 1000 trades and need to compare and merge trades based on same source entry.